# How to test Server-Client (Java/Maven)

Tags: java, maven, testing, client-server

I have a simple game which consists of two projects: Client and server. Now I want to test if they interact correctly.
Setup is: One Maven-parent project, and server/client as child-modules.

I don't now how to test the interaction: am I able to start both project somehow (how exactly?) in junit tests, or integration tests? So that I can listen for one projects output verify it and send it to the other? Or should I go another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for an integration test. I would do it as follows:

- create a third maven module called IntegrationTests
- use a maven profile `integrationtests` and activate it with -Dintegrationtests
- pull in the client and server modules as dependencies in the new module
- write my integration tests using JUnit (@Before, @Test, etc)

As Evgeniy suggested, you could of course put the integration tests in one of the existing modules, whereas my suggestion is to split it out to a third module.

If you need help on how to use maven profiles for integration testing, just google around, or feel free to ask if you have specific questions.

Good luck.

Comment: Thx, I followed http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing but it's only described with a server plugin. How can I start my own?

Comment: You are reading there about the `maven-failsafe-plugin`. To use it, or any other plugin, just configure it in your pom.xml under `<build>` and `<plugins>`, and build your maven project (`clean install`). Myself, I just use the `maven-surefire-plugin`, since it will fail when the test breaks. Either way, it's nice to be able to specify whether integration tests run or not with `-Dintegrationtests`.

Answer (score 1):

For integeation tests create a seperate pom add both projects as  test  dependencies. Then start the server using testng beforeclass hooks or the maven failsafe plugin hook before the test starts, and close the server after the test.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you start the server from test and send requests from the test emulating client behaviour and checking that server reponses are what you expect.